# How to write a function to get the first and last Chars of a String?

Tags: string, function, kotlin, char

I'm trying to call a function to get the first and last letter of a string and turn it into a Char

```
fun main() {
    val kotlin = "Kotlin".getFirstAndLast()
    val dicoding = "Dicoding".getFirstAndLast()

    val kotlinFirstChar = kotlin["first"]
    val kotlinLastChar = kotlin["last"]

    val dicodingFirstChar = dicoding["first"]
    val dicodingLastChar = dicoding["last"]

    println("First char Kotlin is $kotlinFirstChar and $kotlinLastChar for second letter")
    println("First char Dicoding is $dicodingFirstChar and $dicodingLastChar for second letter")

}
```

I need to change the String into Char, it has to be a char. How can I do this?

```
fun String.getFirstAndLast(): Map<String, Char>{

    return mapOf<String,Char>(

            "first" to "${this[0]}",
            "last" to "${this[this.length-1]}"
    )
}
```

Comment: `"${this[0]}"` why are you placing it between the `""`? It converts char to string. Just use `this[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could rewrite the function as follows.

```
fun String.getFirstAndLast() = mapOf("first" to this.first(), "last" to this.last())
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
fun main() {
    fun String.getFirstAndLast() = first() to last()

    val (kotlinFirstChar, kotlinLastChar) = "Kotlin".getFirstAndLast()
    val (dicodingFirstChar, dicodingLastChar) = "Dicoding".getFirstAndLast()

    println("First char Kotlin is $kotlinFirstChar and $kotlinLastChar for last letter")
    println("First char Dicoding is $dicodingFirstChar and $dicodingLastChar for last letter")
}
```

- [`first()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/first.html) gives you the first `Char` of the string.
- [`last()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/last.html) gives you the last `Char` of the string.
- `first() to last()` creates a [`Pair<Char, Char>`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-pair/) of the first and last characters.
- `val (foo, bar) = pair` uses [destructuring](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/multi-declarations.html) to extract the values from the pair.

Result:

```
First char Kotlin is K and n for last letter
First char Dicoding is D and g for last letter
```